# Pipelining using HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, http

I am working on an HTTP client which should ideally pipeline requests when needed. Also, the requests will be sent on specific network interfaces (the client is multihomed).

Asynchronous sockets are used and in order to make a request, I use the following code:

```
        Uri url = new Uri(reqUrl);
        ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(url);
        sp.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(localBind);

        pseg.req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        pseg.req.AddRange("bytes", psegStart, psegStart + psegLength - 1);
        pseg.req.KeepAlive = true;
        pseg.req.Pipelined = true;
```

For each request made using this code, a separate connection to the server is opened and segments received in parallell. This is ok, however, it is not the behavior I want. I want the requests to be pipelined, but the replies to arrive sequentially. If I use locking or set the connectionlimit to 1, the request for segment #2 is not sent until after segment #1 has been fully received.

Is there any way to achieve what I want and still use the HttpWebRequest/Response-classes? Or will I have to drop down to sockets?

Comment: I just did some more experimentation on this. The same behavior is seen when I remove the BindIPEndPoint-call.

Comment: Why are you making Async calls if you `want the segments to be received sequentially`?

Comment: Hi. That is because I dont want any blocking in my application.

Comment: If you want them to arrive in sequence you either need to send them that way, hence block, or you need to receive them in parallel, but hold them until all items are received and then sort them back into order, which I personally see as having at least a degree of blocking.

Comment: The problem is not the receiving, it is the sending. The framework seems to postpone sending the next request until the previous has been fully served, even if the two request calls are made right after another.

Comment: Huh?  You stated `as I want the segments to be received sequentially.` in your question, now you say that you want to send them asynchronously. But your question implies that it is already working asynchronously by saying `For each request made using this code, a separate connection to the server is opened and segments received in parallell.` So what do you actually want?

Comment: If you want to send multiple requests in parallel, you need to use the [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse) on each of the requests you want to make and then call the corresponding [HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.endgetresponse) on each of them.

Comment: You may also want to look at [Issuing Multiple Requests Using HTTP Pipelining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665941/issuing-multiple-requests-using-http-1-1-pipelining) to understand potential issues with the pipeline approach.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not see that mistake in my original question. I am already using BeginGetResponse and EndRespone. The problem is that even with this approach, the request for segment two is sent after the request for segment one has been fully received. I want the segment to be sent while segment one is being received.

Comment: Please edit your code to show the Begin End calls.