# TCP starting without SYN?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, ip, wireshark

I am implementing a sniffer for all tcp traffic in one's computer.

I encountered this weird case - 
When going to `Amazon.com` the TCP that holds the HTML will not start with `SYN flag`.

In `WireShark`, I right-clicked on one of the packets, and pressed `Follow TCP Stream`
The result is as following:-

[image: WireShark screenshot]

What is happening? I know that all TCP streams should start with the 3-way-handshake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is happening?

Since we can't replay the stream, and packet 498 occurs roughly 2.1 seconds after the capture started, we can only guess... however, the most likely scenarios are:

- You started the TCP socket with Amazon just before you pressed capture in wireshark
- The socket started after you captured in Wireshark, but Wireshark delayed capturing packets during the start phase and somehow missed the first few packets of the 192.168.2.41:6097 <--> 205.251.242.54:80 socket.  You got 500 packets in the first two seconds, which is actually a significant load... it's possible that the capture driver was overloaded and missed the 3-way handshake.

> I know that all tcp streams should start with the 3-way-handshake, no?

You are correct.  All TCP streams start with the three-way handshake.  Somehow you managed to miss the handshake in this case; however, this isn't anything to be concerned about.

Comment: I think that I clicked a link inside Amazon website and didn't type "amazon.com" is it possible that the TCP stream remains active between clicks? and therefore the stream that I am seeing is not actually the beginning?

Comment: @RonGross, it's quite possible that the stream was already active before you captured, that's what I was saying in the first bullet.  FYI, if the session is using HTTP 1.1, [Multple HTTP GETs can be active at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2665941/667301)